# Specify font family for Firefox/Chrome on Mac

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I am on OS X 10.8 with Firefox 25, having tried to reset my firefox profile via `about:support`, I still can't get Firefox to recognize this particular `font-family` rule.

```
font-family: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", "Segoe UI Semibold", sans-serif;
```

I tried a few variation, such as `Avenir Next Demi Bold` or `Avenir Next DemiBold`, none of them seem to pick up the DemiBold weight variant; the closest I get is `Avenir Next Demi Bold`, where Firefox appears to select Avenir Next Regular instead.

Chrome and Safari only recognize `AvenirNext-DemiBold`, nothing else work.

So I wonder what's best practice/workaround here? For example, Firefox doesn't display most of the fonts listed on http://iosfonts.com/, while Chrome and Safari does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735872/how-do-i-set-semi-bold-font-via-css-font-weight-of-600-doesnt-make-it-look-l#comment17728212_8736037 Someone mentioned that using font filename may work, but how do I specify its variant without getting into above problem? (As far as I can tell, `font-weight`/`font-variant` are NOT design for this issue)

Comment: the best solution I have found so far is described in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187044/segoe-ui-font-with-font-face-local basic we need to explicitly define a font-face for local variation, Avenir Next, Avenir Next Bold etc...